# How to speed up a treeview population in Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following function that causes a significant visual jittering and lag in my access database - This is a treeview selection based on data in a table (tblDATA) with the fields:

**Object | Attribute | Property | Value**

I have tried `echo` and `me.painting` but figured my actual for loops need to be looked at for optimisation - wondering if there is a better way to cycle through a `Recordset` and populate a Treeview ?

````vb
' [1] Update the treeview
'------------------------------------

Private Sub btnUpdateFilter_Click()
    
    'Me.Painting = False
    'Echo False
    'DoCmd.Hourglass True
    
    Dim sArea As String, N As Integer
    Dim oData_distinct As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oNone As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim Arr_distinct() As Variant
    
    If IsNull(cbxAttributeFilter01) Or IsNull(cbxPropertyFilter01) Then Exit Sub
    

    Set oData_distinct = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Value] FROM tblData WHERE Attribute = " & cbxAttributeFilter01 _
                                                & " AND Property = " & cbxPropertyFilter01, dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    Set oNone = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Tagname] FROM tblData WHERE NOT Attribute = " & cbxAttributeFilter01 _
                                                & " AND NOT Property = " & cbxPropertyFilter01, dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    Set oData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Tagname], [Value] FROM tblData WHERE [Attribute] = " & cbxAttributeFilter01 _
                                                & " AND [Property] = " & cbxPropertyFilter01, dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    
    If oData.RecordCount = 0 Then TreeView.Nodes.Clear: Exit Sub
    
    Arr_distinct = oData_distinct.GetRows(oData_distinct.RecordCount)
    
    TreeView.Nodes.Clear
    
    ' Standard
    TreeView.Nodes.Add , , "MISC", "MISC"
    For Each element In Arr_distinct
        If Not element = "" Then
            If IsNumeric(element) Then element = "_" & element
            TreeView.Nodes.Add , , element, element    ' ADD Parent
        End If
    Next element
    
    Dim sTemp As String
    
    With oData
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            sTemp = !Value
            If IsNumeric(sTemp) Then sTemp = "_" & sTemp
            If sTemp = "" Or sTemp = " " Then sTemp = "MISC"
            On Error Resume Next
            TreeView.Nodes.Add sTemp, tvwChild, DLookup("Tagname", "MASTER", "ID = " & !Tagname), DLookup("Tagname", "MASTER", "ID = " & !Tagname)
        .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
        
    With oNone
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            On Error Resume Next
            TreeView.Nodes.Add "MISC", tvwChild, DLookup("Tagname", "MASTER", "ID = " & !Tagname), DLookup("Tagname", "MASTER", "ID = " & !Tagname)
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
   
   'DoCmd.Hourglass False
   'Echo True
   'Me.Painting = True
   
End Sub
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid the multiple `DLookUp`s with each`TreeView.Nodes.Add` call for *every* row of recordset! At the very least store your `DLookUp` value once and apply it to treeview. This cuts down the repetitive 4 calculations down to 2 for every row.

But since `DLookUp` essentially is a query anyway, simply integrate a `JOIN` to `Master` object in SQL queries of `OpenRecordset` calls. This cuts down the repetitive 4 calculations to 0 for every row.

```vb
sql = "SELECT d.[Tagname], m.[Tagname] AS [MasterTagname] " _
       & "FROM tblData d " _
       & "LEFT JOIN Master m " _
       & "    ON m.ID = d.[Tagname] " _
       & "WHERE NOT d.[Attribute] = " & cbxAttributeFilter01 _
       & "  AND NOT d.[Property] = " & cbxPropertyFilter01

Set oNone = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)

sql = "SELECT d.[Tagname], m.[Tagname] AS [MasterTagname] " _
       & "FROM tblData d " _
       & "LEFT JOIN Master m " _
       & "    ON m.ID = d.[Tagname] " _
       & "WHERE d.[Attribute] = " & cbxAttributeFilter01 _
       & "  AND d.[Property] = " & cbxPropertyFilter01

Set oData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot) 

...

TreeView.Nodes.Add sTemp, tvwChild, !MasterTagname, !MasterTagname

...

TreeView.Nodes.Add "MISC", tvwChild, !MasterTagname, !MasterTagname
```

Also, best practice in VBA is to never use `On Error Resume Next` but to handle any error that raises which in this case may be a missing or `Null` `DLookUp` result. Therefore, enclose `If` logic.

```vb
...

If Not IsNull(!MasterTagName)
   TreeView.Nodes.Add sTemp, tvwChild, !MasterTagname, !MasterTagname
End If

...

If Not IsNull(!MasterTagName)
   TreeView.Nodes.Add "MISC", tvwChild, !MasterTagname, !MasterTagname
End If
```